# PDF of the sum distribution of a Laplace and a Gamma distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $X,Y$ be independent randomly distributed continuous variables with the following PDF

$f_X(x) = \frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda\mid x \mid}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$f_Y(y) = \lambda^2ye^{-\lambda y}$

What's the PDF of the sum distribution $Z = X + Y$?

**My working:**

I've found out that $X \sim Laplace(0,\frac{1}{\lambda})$ and $Y \sim Gamma(2,\frac{1}{\lambda})$.

I'm willing to apply the following formula (which I think is the correct way to go):

$f_Z(z) = \int_\mathbb{R} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x) dx$.

So I calculate $f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)$ (using MATLAB) and I get

$f_X(x)f_Y(z-x) = -\frac{1}{2}(\lambda^3e^{-\lambda\mid x \mid}e^{\lambda(x-z)}(x - z)$.

Now, when I integrate with respect to x, I dont get any sensible results, and I assume that's because I'm not getting the integration limits correctly.

How are the appropiate integration limits found?

Comment: it is a serious error avoiding to state which is the dependence structure between $X$ and $Y$

Comment: You can't answer this question without more information on the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$... maybe they are independent ?

Comment: They are, indeed, independent. My mistake I missed it, sorry

Answer (score 2):

long calculations to me (I am not familiar with long calculations) but easy exercise:

Set $Z=X+Y$ and $U=Y$. After verifying that Jacobian is 1, the joint density of $(U,Z)$ is

$$f_{UZ}(u,z)=\frac{\lambda^3}{2}ue^{-\lambda u}e^{-\lambda|z-u|}$$

Now to get $f_Z(z)$ you have to integrate in $du$. To do that observe that:

IF $Z<0$ the expression inside the module is always $<0$ thus

$$f_{UZ}(u,z)=\frac{\lambda^3}{2}e^{\lambda z}\cdot ue^{-2\lambda u}$$

and

$$f_Z(z)=\frac{\lambda^3}{2}e^{\lambda z}\int_0^{\infty} ue^{-2\lambda u}du=\frac{\lambda}{8}e^{\lambda z}$$

IF $Z>0$ you have to integrate accordingly splitting the module...

After some easy but tedious calculations the result is the following:

$$  f_Z(z) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda}{8}e^{\lambda z},  & \text{if $z<0$ } \\
\frac{\lambda^3}{4}e^{-\lambda z}\left[z^2+\frac{2\lambda z+1}{2\lambda^2}\right], & \text{if $z\geq 0$ }
\end{cases}$$

---

Just as an example, setting $\lambda=1$ this is the resulting density

[image]

Comment: If $z>0$ it will deppend on the value of u whether the expression inside the module is positive or negative. How do I deal with that?

Comment: @JenaRayner come on! simply solve the integral splitting the module. Upvoting and accepting my answer perhaps will encourage me to do more calculations for you

Comment: Two further questions to accept your answers

1) In the z>=0 case, is the second summand $2\lambda z+1$ or $2\lambda (z+1)$
2) Is it a correct conclusion then to say that $X+Y \sim Gamma(3, \lambda )$

Comment: @JenaRayner : I live also without your acceptance.